# <template> syntax for ngclass or [class.classname]

Tags: angular

I have seen the syntax for ngfor, ngIf and ngSwitch with template, can anyone help me with, if I want to use ngclass or [class.classname] with template syntax in angular 2.

How i can use the class with template syntax in angular 2

Comment: Please show the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed (with exact error message). See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgForOf-directive.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `<ng-container>` instead of `<template>` you can use the same syntax as everywhere else.

Comment: getting an exception after using the ng-container

https://puu.sh/vdli9/53ce203054.png

Comment: The error message doesn't help without the code that causes it.